# How to get attributes out of an event of Google-Calendar?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

In the Last days I tried to read attributes out of an event of Google-calendar

So currently I have only achived to get the event-ID out of my calendar.

Code:

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Calendar;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
            query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/my@e-mail.com/public/basic");
            query.NumberToRetrieve = 10;
            query.StartTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            query.EndTime = System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);
            CalendarService service = new CalendarService(appName);
            service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);

            EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);

            foreach (EventEntry feedEntry in calFeed.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event ID: " + feedEntry.EventId);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I tried `feedEntry.Title.Text` to get the Title ... but its always "busy"

So my question is:

Ho Can I Get informations out of my Event?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is:

```
 query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/my@e-mail.com/public/basic");
```

has to be :

```
 query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/my@e-mail.com/private/full");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should migrate off this approach altogether. Gdata is a deprecated Calendar API and will be shut down in November: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.at/2014/07/upgrade-now-to-calendar-apiv3.html

Use Events.List in the Calendar API v3 https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/